# How to improve MySQL insertion performance using WSO2 CEP

Tags: mysql, performance, wso2, wso2-cep

I tried to do insertions and updates to MySQL database using WSO2 CEP, but CEP performance is very low in that case. I could be able to achieve, nearly 600 insertions per second when using siddhi query (Event Tables) for insertion. And when using publisher, it performs much more than siddhi, nearly 1.5 k insertions per second. I tried to measure MySQL performance using standalone java program. At that time I was able to achieve the 6-7 k insertions per second.

How do I improve the performance of CEP to increase the MySQL db insertion rate using siddhi, or publisher?

WSO2 CEP is running with 8 cores, 16GB RAM.

Comment: First off, this question is offtopic - there's no code, there's no configuration question, nothing. You're asking directly about someone else's program, so the only way for you to get what you want is to contact people who made that program and ask them how to get more out of your MySQL. You don't even know why MySQL is performing like it is, is it constrained by I/O or CPU, and bouncing back and forth with commands for you to run will result in endless discussion. Contact the tech support of that wso2 server. This is wrong place for such questions.